# Set a substring equal to a literal

Tags: c++

I am trying to change the extension of a file from '.xxx' to '.err'  (xxx is whatever).  Here is my code:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<strlen(m_sMFLfile); i++) {
  errorfile[i] = m_sMFLfile[i];
  if(m_sMFLfile[i] == '.') {
    errorfile[i,i+3] = ".err";
    break;
    }
 }
```

However, I get:
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'char'
errorfile is defined as:

```
char          errorfile[256];
```

Can't seem to answer this post for some reason, but here is what I understand I need to do:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<strlen(m_sMFLfile); i++) {
  errorfile[i] = m_sMFLfile[i];
  if(m_sMFLfile[i] == '.') {
    errorfile[i+1] = 'e';
    errorfile[i+2] = 'r';
    errorfile[i+3] = 'r';
    break;
    }
  }
```

Gawd help me if it is 1000 chars long...

Comment: 2 problems with this line `errorfile[i,i+3] = '.err';` (1) `[i,i+3]` you can't use array indexing to create a range, (2) the quote `'` is used for single characters.

Comment: Note that `'.err'` is an `int` literal, not a string literal. There are also several other severe issues with your code. In particular the expressions `i,i+3` (comma operator) and `m_sMFLfile[i] == '.'` (a pointer comparison) definitely do not do what you think they do.

Comment: @RichardCritten I changed ' to ", but I still get error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'char'

Comment: @Adrian `errorfile[i,i+3]` does not do what you want you need to use a loop and copy the characters 1 at a time.  To be technical the part `errorfile[i,i+3]` evaluates `i` and throws away the result, then evaluates `i+3` and uses the result to index the array. See [Built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: @RichardCritten like :              errorfile[i] = ".";
              errorfile[i+1] = "e";
              errorfile[i+2] = "r";
              errorfile[i+3] = "r";

Comment: Given what you're doing, you might find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580014/179910 (though it may not lead to a practical solution for you).

Comment: Instead of a char array, you could perhaps use `filesystem::path` to store the filename. As it happens, it has a [replace_extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/replace_extension) member that does all the work.